# Two identical loops but the second one continues infinitely

Tags: c, loops

Expected output of program is to print a border of a specified character around a sentence input by the user.

```
//program: border.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int argu = argc - 1;

    if(argu < 1){
        printf("usage: border arguments are the text to border.\n");
    }

    else{
        printf("Enter the character for the border: ");
        char in = getchar();//get the character input by user
        int size;
        for(int i = 1; i <= argu; i++){// gets the count of the characters in the string
            size += strlen(argv[i]);
            size += 1; //to compensate for spaces
        }

        printf("%d", size);
        printf("\n");
        size += 2;

        for( int a = 0; a <= size ; a++){
            printf("%c", in); // prints the first border line
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("%c%*c\n", in, size, in);//prints second line of border line.

        printf("%c", in);
        printf(" ");
        for( int i = 1; i <= argu; i++){//prints the sentence that was typed.
            printf("%s " , argv[i]);
        }
        printf("%c", in);
        printf("\n");

        printf("%c%*c\n", in, size, in);// same as the second line.
        printf("%d", size);



        for( int b = 0; b <= size ; b++){    //causing the infinite loop
            printf("%c", in);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

My first loop works fine:

```
    for( int a = 0; a <= size ; a++){
        printf("%c", in); // prints the first border line
    }
```

but when I included the second one, which is identical, it caused my program to continue infinately.

```
    for( int b = 0; b <= size ; b++){
        printf("%c", in);
    }
```

Comment: Note: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char` for good reasons. Always check for `EOF`!

Comment: `size` is not initialized. The behavior is undefined. It may be just coincidence that it was working the first time.

Comment: @AlexD is correct... ultimately SIZE is the problem... the problem was not the two loops... the problem were these lines: printf("%c%*c\n", in, size, in); .... they use SIZE as a count of the number of characters to print.  Read the man page for printf's handling of a negative value.

Comment: Since you want to calculate `size` by adding to it, change `int size;` to `int size=0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you never initialize `size` which means it has some random value.  So you end up printing a number of border characters equal to that random value plus the intended length of the border.

If you do this:

```
int size = 0;
```

That will solve the problem.  Sample input/output:

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ ./x1 test text
Enter the character for the border: x
10
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
x           x
x test text x
x           x
12xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So now we see that there's a number stuck at the bottom border.  That's because you're printing `size` before the bottom border, so you should move that `printf` to after the loop to print that border.

So change this:

```
    printf("%c%*c\n", in, size, in);// same as the second line.
    printf("%d", size);

    for( int b = 0; b <= size ; b++){    //causing the infinite loop
        printf("%c", in);
    }
```

To this:

```
    printf("%c%*c\n", in, size, in);// same as the second line.

    for( int b = 0; b <= size ; b++){    //causing the infinite loop
        printf("%c", in);
    }
    printf("%d", size);  // this line moved down
```